# Accessing an attribute of a linked model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So, sorry if this doesn't come across coherently... I don't know all my Ruby / Rails terminology (yet).

I have a model called "Profile" and a model called "User, and the two are linked like this:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :profile
```

Now, in the "index" and "show" views of profiles that I made, I want to be able to access the attribute "name" from the User model.  How can I do this?  I imagine I'll need something in the controller that looks like this:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

And then access it in the view like this:

```
<%= @user.name %>
```

But that bit of code right there doesn't work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: please give more details about how 'doesn't work'. any error screen?

Answer (score 4):

If the attribute `name` belongs to the **Profile** model, in your view:

```
<%= @user.profile.name %>
```

---

If the attribute `name` belongs to the **User** model, please stop the server, run `rake db:migrate` to be sure every migration has been applied to your database; then run `rails console` or `ruby script/console` to check if the attribe is working for your model:

```
> u = User.first
> u.name
```

If the last command returns an empty string or the name of your first user, everything is working. If you get a `NoMethodError: undefined method` you should check your database as the column that should handle the `name` attribute is probably missing.

Comment: Thanks for this!  The attribute 'name' is a part of the User model, and when I run the rails console commands, I get back the string of the first User in the DB.  That said, how do I access the User.name in the Profile view?

Comment: Please try to `<%= @user.inspect %>` instead of `<%= @user.name %>` to see if the record you are expecting to load has been properly loaded in the controller. Edit and reload the view in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should work. That part is correct.

**a few questions**

Does your profile have a user_id ?

Did you run a migration that created attributes user_id for `Profile` and profile_id for `User` ?

Comment: There is a user_id attribute in 'Profile', but there is not a profile_id attribute in 'User'.  Should there be?  Also, the user_id column is blank in each profile when I check the SQL DB.  That... can't be right.

Comment: Hmm.. were Profiles created **after** you implemented the relation in the models?