# Accessing a linked model's attribute for output in a table

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, model

This helped for display on an individual 'items' show page
[Accessing an attribute of a linked model in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839480/accessing-an-attribute-of-a-linked-model-in-rails)

However I'm having trouble doing the same for an 'all items table'

```
...
<% @items.each do |item| %>
...
<td><%= item.room.name %></td>
...
```

Clearly where one room has many items.

only this works:

```
<td><%= item.room_id %></td>
```

I can't seem to use it there, gives:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: `item.room` is `nil`.  Do you have a room for that item?

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW So how can I make this work then?

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW Not all items in the table have rooms, is this my problem?

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW Yes! thankyou! It's fine, I just hadn't added a room for all the items yet! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Rails' [Delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) module:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  delegate :name, :to => :room, :allow_nil => true, :prefix => :room
end
```

This will add the instance method `room_name` to `Item`, which will fail more gracefully (returning `nil` if there is no room, instead of the `NilClass` error).

Comment: Yes, thanks this works. I had planned for every item to be in a room anyway, just haven't done validation yet! Thanks. (Thanks also to @D3mon-1stVFW)