# Accessing a linked list attribute model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

According to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839480/accessing-an-attribute-of-a-linked-model-in-rails) 
How to code in Rails if we have more linked table using belongs_to. 
For the following:

```
class Article
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps
field :name, :type => String
field :content, :type => String
field :published_on, :type => Date
belongs_to :author
embeds_many :comments
validates_presence_of :name
end

class Author
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps
field :name, :type => String
belongs_to :contacts
end

class Contact
include Mongoid::Document
field :email, type: String
field :phone, type: String
field :line, type: String
end
```

Then how I could access email if my console look like this:

```
> a 
=> #<Article _id: 5509afbb4d42500909010000, created_at: nil, updated_at: 2015-03-19 09:55:41 UTC, name: "Pr", content: "My Content", published_on: nil, author_id: nil> 

> au
=> #<Author _id: 551270b94d42500a09000000, created_at: 2015-03-25 08:24:25 UTC, updated_at: 2015-03-25 08:24:25 UTC, name: "Tim", address_id: nil, contacts_id: 1> 

> c
=> #<Contact _id: 55237a7d4d425002df040000, email: "myemail.com", phone: "213 999999", line: "k.0">
```

I can access name by

```
> a.name
=> "Pr"
```

Question:
How I can access email ?

```
> a.email
NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for #<Article:0x007fed681d8280>
```

Thanks

Comment: `@user.contact.email`... will be enough. Note: `users` table should have the column `contact_id`..

Comment: I have "NoMethodError: undefined method `contact'

Comment: I will rewrite my question instead of the extension from  previous question

Comment: Oh! you are using `mongoid`.. Humm

Comment: I believed it the same as activerecord. I just don't know the basic. Your comment / answer might help. Thanks Arup

Comment: Please try now and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define associations as :

```
class Article
  #...
  embeds_one :contact
  #..
end
```

and

```
class Contact
  #..
  embedded_in :article
  #...
end
```

Then, do `a.contact.email`. Read [Embedded 1-1](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/relations.html#embeds_one) for more information.

Comment: If embedded it worked but how about Contact is its own separated table.  Should I call a.contact.email?

Comment: @T.Kul I didn't get you. I just created a `1-to-1` association. `Contact` is still a separate table..

Comment: What I like to learn if I should call table1.table2.fieldIntable3

Comment: @T.Kul When you are writing `a.contact.email`, you are calling a method named `contact` on the object `a` which is instance of `Author`. Now `a.contact` gives you a object of `Contact`, on which you are calling the reader method `email`.. Does it make sense ?